# Validation message does not go away when "validation-passed"

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation

I am validating my address fields for numbers. 

 In some countries house number is mandatory to make the delivery. 
Since I don't care which field the number is written in, I want the validation to be stopped for both fields if one of the fields contains a number.

I came up with this:

```
var digvalenable = function(){
  var val1 = document.getElementById('street_1');
  var val2 = document.getElementById('street_2');

  if ((/\d/.test(val1.value))  || (/\d/.test(val2.value))) {
    val1.classList.remove("validate-digits");
    val2.classList.remove("validate-digits");

  } else {
    val1.classList.add("validate-digits");
    val2.classList.add("validate-digits");
  }
Validation.validate($('street_1'));
Validation.validate($('street_2'));
}
```

Which basically adds the validation class if a number is not present and removes it if there is a number.

It works great, except the message for my number validation does not disappear (I can save the value- validation-passed)

**EDIT**

Currently I am solving this by:

```
document.getElementById('advice-validate-digits-street_1').style = "display:none";
```

But this does not have the fade out effect...

Comment: What is it what are tyring to achieve exactly? Just a fade out on the validation  message?

Comment: I thought that it would fade out and disappear automatically like it does with Magento usually, but for whatever reason it is not happening. I am trying to find a reason why.

Comment: Nothing happens by itself unless you tell something to do so :) Two question to help you further. Do you have jQuery available on the specific page? And on which event do you want to do the fade out of the validation message?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am no stranger to this. But I thought since I remove the validation class from input tag and then validate the field, it should update and fade out the message as it normally does

Comment: Currently I am just using only prototype js, but so far it has been sufficient. Well, as I said, I thought the fade out would happen as I update the validation.

Comment: So is the problem solved? Or...?

Comment: well, I am looking for the reason why I had to do this extra step. It is "solved" but It is not "generic"